# Why do expectations not scale with probabilities?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The expected number of coin flips to get to 3 consecutive 1s or 4s in a row (meaning you can get 114, 111, 444, 411, etc) is 39. The expected number of coin flips to get 3 consecutive 1s in a row is 258.

A: The probability of getting 3 consecutive 1s/4s is (1/3)(1/3)(1/3) = 1/27

B: The probability of getting 3 consecutive 1s is (1/6)(1/6)(1/6) = 1/216 = 1/(27*8). TAKEAWAY: B IS 8X LESS LIKELY THAN A IS

Why is the expected number of coin flips to get B not 8 times the number of coin flips to get A? 8*39 = 312, not 258.

Comment: "*the probability of getting...TAKEAWAY...*"  Those are correct answers to an *irrelevant* problem.  You should be looking instead at the probability of first getting 3 consecutive 1s/4s by the third, fourth, fifth, ..., n'th flip compared to the probability of first getting 3 consecutive 1s by the third, fourth, fifth, ..., n'th flip.  You will find that apart from the case of hitting the mark by the third flip, the rest of the cases are *not* at an 8:1 ratio.

Comment: Okay, gotcha, that is helpful. How do I then find what this ratio converges to?

Comment: Why should it matter what the ratio *converges* to?  What does that have to do with the original question being asked of expected number of flips?  Sure... if the ratio were *constant* then that could be an approach... but it is not constant.

Comment: If I want to find the expectation of B, using the expectation of A, and using the ratio of the probabilities of A and B.

Comment: That would be helpful if the ratio were *constant*, but the ratio is not.  This is a bad approach for this problem.